# Count The Number Of Users With Value 1 When logged On

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table called user in my database.

I have a column name called `isLogged` on my `user` row.

And when the user `islogged` on it changes to `'1'`. And logged out changes to `'0'`.

What is the best way to count the users that have `'1'` in the isLogged column.

**model**

```
public function getTotalUserOnline() {
// Only Counts Number Of Users 
$query = $this->db->count_all('user');
return $query;
}
```

and then echo it from controller.

```
$data['total_user_online'] = $this->dashboard_user_online_model->getTotalUserOnline();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Codeigniter, you can do

```
public function getTotalUserOnline() {
        $this->db->select('count(*) as total');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('isLogged', 1);
        $data = $this->db->get()->result();

        return $data[0]->total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total_user_online FROM users WHERE isLogged = 1
```

fetch row `$data['total_user_online']`